# Issue with using the Hyperledger-Composer developer-tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-composer

## hyperledger-composer

I followed the steps from the blockchain developer-tutorial at:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

My startFabric.sh fails with
Error response from daemon:

`Container d2a4df08857333ddc46026fe26376af58116af8d39af2823e222aeebedddb648 is not running`

```
ibm@pradi0514075029:~/fabric-dev-servers$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
d2a4df088573 hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0 "peer node start" About an hour ago Exited (2) About an hour ago peer0.org1.example.com
0f690b2a6629 hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6 "tini -- /docker-ent…" About an hour ago Up About an hour 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp couchdb
8cde7086fd80 hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…" About an hour ago Up About an hour 0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp ca.org1.example.com
4e9dd5b6d33f hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0 "orderer" About an hour ago Up About an hour 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp orderer.example.com
```

It seems today that my peer container has exited.
I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (xenial).

Comment: please format your question in a better way...

Answer (score 0):

looks like your peer stopped. You could try starting it again using `docker start` Should have 4Gb memory available. If it persists suggest to do a teardown, remove the old PeerAdmin card and run startFabric again, following the sequence shown in Controlling your dev environment https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a correction in another answer.
Adding GODEBUG=netdns=go to environment variables of peer, orderer, ca, couchdb in docker-compose.yml

Try ./startFabric.sh again and finally OK.

At least, that is working for me.